# How to register QObject class in CMake with qt_add_qml_module?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qml

I have a `QObject` derived class `Expense` that I use in QML like this.

```
// main.qml
Expense {
  id: expenseManager
  onExpenseCreated: {
      // Do something
  }
}
```

The expense class has no UI components, it has some basic Signal and Slots for API communications.

```
// expense.h

#ifndef EXPENSE_H
#define EXPENSE_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QString>

#include "service.h"

class Expense : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    Service service;
    void networkError();
    bool buttonLock = false;

public:
    explicit Expense(QObject *parent = nullptr);


public slots:
    void createInvoice(QString item, float amount);

signals:
    void expenseCreated();

};

#endif // EXPENSE_H
```

I have used `qmlRegisterType()` for registering `Expense` type in QML. Below is how my `main()` looks like.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    ......


    qmlRegisterType<Expense>("com.kadbyte.expense", 1, 0, "Expense");

    ........
    return app.exec();
}
```

Everything working perfectly as it used to. But recently I have upgraded my project to QT6 with CMake as the build tool instead of QMake. In the docs I saw that we can use `qt_add_qml_module` command in CMakeList.txt to register C++ Classes instead of `qmlRegisterType()`, by adding `QML_ELEMENT` macro to the QObject class.

But I can't understand how to do this, the documentation doesn't make sense as it uses qmake example ([Link to docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-cppintegration-definetypes.html#registering-an-instantiable-object-type)) instead of CMake. Below is my CMakeLists.txt file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(Udyan VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt6 6.2 COMPONENTS Quick REQUIRED)

qt_add_executable(appUdyan
    main.cpp
    expense.h expense.cpp
)

qt_add_qml_module(appUdyan
    URI Udyan
    VERSION 1.0
    QML_FILES qml/main.qml
)

set_target_properties(appUdyan PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER my.example.com
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

target_compile_definitions(appUdyan
    PRIVATE $<$<OR:$<CONFIG:Debug>,$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>>:QT_QML_DEBUG>)

target_link_libraries(appUdyan
    PRIVATE Qt6::Quick)
```

So how to use `qt_add_qml_module` to registering QObject class to use in QML?

Note: All the example I have given above is just an MRE and not my complete code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to add `QML_ELEMENT` to your QObject-derived `Expense` class's header and make sure you have moc enabled in your CMakeLists.txt. In application case it doesn't matter if the expense.h/cpp sources are included via `qt_add_executable` or `qt_add_qml_module`. I think it's clearer to add them to `qt_add_qml_module` *SOURCES*. Then you just import module URI in you QML file. In the example below I'm printing out property value from Expense object in QML.

CMakeLists.txt

```
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

qt_add_qml_module(appUdyan
    URI udyan
    VERSION 1.0
    QML_FILES
        main.qml
    SOURCES
        expense.h
        expense.cpp
)
```

C++

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QtQml/qqmlregistration.h>

class Expense : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QML_ELEMENT
    Q_PROPERTY(int value READ value NOTIFY valueChanged)
public:
    explicit Expense(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    int value() const;

signals:
    void valueChanged();

private:
    int m_value {5};
};
```

QML:

```
import QtQuick
import udyan

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Expense {
        id: expense
        Component.onCompleted: console.log(expense.value)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked!. but any idea why the QML editor still complaing `QML module not found (udyan)`?

Comment: It's a "false positive", code works but Qt Creator IDE code completion shows error. IDE is not able to keep up with new features. Obviously this bug https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-26454 which will be fixed in Qt Creator 7.

Comment: That make sense. Thanks.

Comment: I was able to make that error go away by adding set(QML_IMPORT_PATH "./") to my CMakeLists.txt. You probably want to use the list function if you're actually managing your files properly.